# Indentation exception clarification

Tags: python

I started learning python lately ,what I am doing here is produce the Indentation error exception and try to except that . But still the error is produced though the exception is correct (`IndentationError`). Please help me understand why is that.

```
try:
    print('Hello')
        print('Hello Aries')
except IndentationError:
    print('Hello World')
```

Comment: Errors with indentation are part of the source code parsing stage, because they are syntax errors, not runtime errors. They occur before your program even has a chance to run. This makes sense if you think about it: Why should the interpreter ever want to attempt to execute source code which it knows is syntactically incorrect?

Comment: I may have said something that doesn't quite make sense: The interpreter doesn't step through your Python source code, and executes it line-by-line. It executes Python byte-code, which is generated after the parsing stage. Byte-code can only be generated if the parser finds no syntactical errors with your source code. The point is, syntax errors are not runtime errors, so you cannot catch them. The only way you could catch them is if you're `eval`ing something, but that's a different story.

Comment: Indentation is part of the syntax of Python code and is used to determine what it means — unlike in many other languages, there for you need to learn it. Real-world code would never have a `try` / `except IndentationError` in it because it means it contains invalid code.

Comment: @Paul M , martineau , thanks a lot. The explanation was so clear and I am out of confusion now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error will not get caught by the `except`, because the checking of indentation errors are done by your code editor before the code is being passed to the python interpreter to run. The `except` command only works when the code has been passed onto the interpreter to run. When you try to run this piece of code, your code editor will raise the `IndentationError` first, and will not actually try to run it using python interpreter.

To test out `except`, you can refer to a non-existent variable, and `except NameError`. This is because variables are dynamic, they are not always specifically declared in code. The program can create some variables as it is running. Thus the code editor cannot be 100% sure that the variable you referenced to will not be valid by the time the code executes to that line. Thus in this case, the code editor will not raise the error, and will allow it to be passed onto the interpreter, which will then correctly catch the `NameError`.

Here is a simple example:

```
try:
    print(hi)
except NameError:
    print('error!')
```

The variable 'hi' is not defined anywhere, thus it will raise a `NameError` which will be caught by `except`.